# Tempered Iwahori-spherical representations

Tags: rt.representation-theory, reductive-groups, p-adic-groups, local-fields

Consider a local field $F$ of characteristic 0 and $G=GL_n(F)$.

It is well known (for example Cartiers article in Corvallis) that an admissible, irreducible representation $\pi$ of $G$ has a nontrivial vector which is fixed by the Iwahori-subgroup of $G$ iff it is a subrepresentation of an unramified principal series.

The representation $\pi$ is called *tempered* if the central character $\omega_\pi$ is unitary and the matrix coefficients of $\pi$ are contained in $L^{2+\epsilon}(PGL_n(F))$ for all $\epsilon >0$.

Is there a classification (for example in terms of the Satake parameter of the containing unramified principal series) when a Iwahori-spherical $\pi$ is tempered?

Comment: I would look in Schneider-Zink.

Answer (score 1):

In Jacquet's *Generic Representations* in Non-Commutative Harmonic Analysis, he shows:

**Proposition.** Tempered representations of $\mathrm{GL}_n$ are of the form $I_P^G(\pi_1\boxtimes\cdots\boxtimes \pi_r)$, where $P\subset G$ is a parabolic subgroup and $\pi_i$ are square-integrable representations.

A standard fact is that the only square-integrable Iwahori-spherical representation of $\mathrm{GL}_n$ is $\phi\cdot\mathrm{St}_G$ for some unitary unramified character $\phi$ (which follows, e.g., from Zelevinsky's classification). Thus, tempered Iwahori-spherical representations of $\mathrm{GL}_n$ are of the form $I_P^G(\phi_1\mathrm{St}\boxtimes\cdots\boxtimes \phi_r\mathrm{St})$ for unitary unramified characters $\phi_1,\dots,\phi_r$.

In particular suppose $P$ corresponds to the partition $n_1+\cdots+n_r=n$. Each $\phi_i$ is of the form $\phi_i(a)=z_i^{v_F(a)}$ for some complex number $z_i$ such that $|z_i|=1$. Now the corresponding Satake parameter is the "union" over $i$ of $(q^{-(n_i-1)/2}z_i,\dots,q^{(n_i-1)/2}z_i)$.